# H2 INSERT SELECT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE throws "Unique index or primary key violation" error

Tags: sql, h2, on-duplicate-key

H2 (started with MODE=MYSQL on) supports INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement only with VALUES clause, while throws a "Unique index or primary key violation" error when using INSERT SELECT statement.

Here is an example:

```
-- creating a simple table
CREATE TABLE test_table1 (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- inserting a value
INSERT INTO test_table1
VALUES (1, 'test1');

-- trying to insert on duplicate key update: it works!
INSERT INTO test_table1
VALUES (1, 'test2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='test2';

-- trying using INSERT SELECT: it throws Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.TEST_TABLE1(ID)"
INSERT INTO test_table1
SELECT 1, 'test2'
FROM test_table1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value='test2';
```

I'm using H2 db version 1.4.192.
Is it a bug? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not using MySql, I'm using H2 version 1.4.192 (question updated)

Answer (score 0):

On you H2 console, if you have 'HIBERNATE_SEQUENCES' table make sure to check what is the `NEXT_VAL` for `SEQUENCE_NAME = 'default'`.

In my case, I had 2 row (insert statement) in my /src/main/resources/data.sql and the `NEXT_VAL` was 2 which was causing problems. I changed to 3 with update statement, and it now works fine.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there something wrong with my code?

Yes, there is.  Why are you inserting into an auto-increment column?  You should be specifying the columns with non-autogenerated data.  So:

```
INSERT INTO test_table1(value)
    VALUES ('test1');
```

And:

```
INSERT INTO test_table1(value)
    SELECT 'test2'
    FROM test_table1
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

Your are getting the error because `ON DUPLICATE KEY` resets `value`, but that has nothing to do with the primary key on the table.

Comment: I don't think so, i tried with  id INT NOT NULL and I had same result. I'm going to update question removing AUTOINCREMENT